# Drupal 8, error on order view page

Tags: views, 8, commerce

I'm working on a Drupal 8 / Drupal Commerce website, and I run into "Website encountered unexpected error" when trying to access /admin/commerce/orders/* pages (order view page).

In log messages I get :

```
Error : Unsupported operand types dans Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement() (/---/core/modules/views/src/Element/View.php ligne 49)
#0 [internal function]: Drupal\views\Element\View::preRenderViewElement(Array)
#1 /---/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(378): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#2 /---/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(195): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, false)
#...
#10 /---/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(437): Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('commerce_order', Array)
```

So it seems that a view displayed on these pages causes this error. Does anyone ran into this error ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

After some debugging, I found that in

```
/core/modules/views/src/Element/View.php L49
$element += $view->element;
```

...$view is null, which causes the error. Above that line, $view is defined by this line (L43) :

```
$view = Views::getView($element['#name']);
```

...and $element['#name'] = commerce_order_item_table.

The View::getView() method is :

```
public static function getView($id) {
  $view = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage('view')->load($id); // this call returns null
  if ($view) {
    return static::executableFactory()->get($view);
  }
}
```

So it seems that I miss a view (commerce_order_item_total) ?...
I'll report further info here.

**EDIT 2**

My missing view seems to be defined in

```
/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/config/install/views.view.commerce_order_item_table.yml
```

...but is not found apparently.

**EDIT3**

On /admin/config/development/configuration/single/export (exporting a single element), selectting "view" as configuration type, I cannot find "commerce_order_item_table". Doing a manual full export (drush cex --destination=sync) I don't find a views.view.commerce_order_item_table in sync folder.

Comment: Did you search the issue queue? https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/commerce?text=Website+encountered+unexpected+error&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=All&component=All

Comment: No, good idea...

Comment: I didn't find anything in this queue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out why my order views disappeared, but I was able to import them back using configuration synchronization :

https://www.drupal.org/node/2917828#comment-12321847

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but with a different view for commerce_orders, views.view.commerce_activity.yml, when viewing an order as an admin.

Export the view then importing the view with content synchronization did the trick.